# SQL Query to Get Users With Role Subscriber

Tags: sql, wordpress

I haven't got any luck with my SQL query to get users with role subscriber:

```
SELECT 
      ID, 
      display_name 
FROM 'wp_users' 
INNER JOIN 'wp_usermeta' ON 'wp_users'.ID = 'wp_usermeta'.user_id 
WHERE 'wp_usermeta'.meta_key = 'wp_capabilities' 
AND ('wp_usermeta'.meta_value LIKE 'subscriber') ORDER BY display_name
```

Can any body help me?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I have got the answer to my question:

```
SELECT wp_users.ID, wp_users.user_nicename 
FROM wp_users INNER JOIN wp_usermeta 
ON wp_users.ID = wp_usermeta.user_id 
WHERE wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'wp_capabilities' 
AND wp_usermeta.meta_value LIKE '%subscriber%' 
ORDER BY wp_users.user_nicename
```

If anybody struggling with the same issue please use my SQL query above.

Comment: It's Working for my side

Answer (score 7):

Here's a slight variant of @qqruza's answer that includes the user's email and role and returns users for all roles.

```sql
SELECT wp_users.ID, wp_users.user_nicename, wp_users.user_email, wp_usermeta.meta_value 
     FROM wp_users 
     JOIN wp_usermeta ON wp_users.ID = wp_usermeta.user_id 
     WHERE wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'wp_capabilities'
     ORDER BY wp_users.user_nicename
```

If you have a WordPress multisite installation, to get the roles for all child sites, use:

```sql
SELECT wp_users.ID, wp_users.user_nicename, wp_users.user_email, wp_usermeta.meta_key, wp_usermeta.meta_value 
     FROM wp_users 
     JOIN wp_usermeta ON wp_users.ID = wp_usermeta.user_id 
     WHERE wp_usermeta.meta_key LIKE 'wp_%capabilities'
     ORDER BY wp_users.user_nicename
```

Of course, you'll need to look at the `wp_usermeta.meta_key` value to determine which child site (blog) the record applies to.

Comment: Hi, the role returned is something like this `role: "a:1:{s:13:"administrator";b:1;}"`. How can one go about extracting only the `administrator` part from the value?

Comment: That is a PHP serialized value. You could use some SQL string manipulation to search for `{s:13:"administrator";b:`. But the most reliable way of parsing it is to use PHP to deserialize. Of course, that's not a SQL-only solution.

Answer (score 3):

This Worked for me :

```
     SELECT a.ID, a.user_login  
     FROM wp_users a
     JOIN wp_usermeta b ON a.ID = b.user_id 
     WHERE b.meta_key = 'wp_capabilities' and b.meta_value like '%contributor%'
     ORDER BY a.user_nicename
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with the WordPress internal structure, but I can tell you that your `LIKE` statement is probably wrong. There's no implicit/automatic wildcards in the LIKE argument, so what you have (with no wildcards) is basically the same as using `=`.  Ie. you probably want:

```
'wp_usermeta'.meta_value LIKE '%subscriber%'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( array( 'role' => 'Subscriber' ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to grab other metainfo you can use subqueries, just remember the more subqueries, the slower the overall query is going to be.

```
SELECT 
    ID, 
    user_email,
    (SELECT `meta_value` FROM wp_usermeta WHERE wp_usermeta.user_id=wp_users.ID AND `wp_usermeta`.`meta_key` = 'first_name') as first_name,
    (SELECT `meta_value` FROM wp_usermeta WHERE wp_usermeta.user_id=wp_users.ID AND `wp_usermeta`.`meta_key` = 'last_name') as last_name,
    user_registered
FROM wp_users
JOIN wp_usermeta ON wp_usermeta.user_id = wp_users.ID
WHERE `meta_value` LIKE '%subscriber%';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id,
       user_email,
       (SELECT meta_value
        FROM   wp_usermeta
        WHERE  wp_usermeta.user_id = wp_users.id
               AND wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'first_name') AS first_name,
       (SELECT meta_value
        FROM   wp_usermeta
        WHERE  wp_usermeta.user_id = wp_users.id
               AND wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'last_name')  AS last_name,
       user_registered
FROM   wp_users
       JOIN wp_usermeta
         ON wp_usermeta.user_id = wp_users.id
WHERE meta_value  LIKE '%subscriber%'
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted solution assumes that the table prefix is 'wp_' which is fine but seldom the case anymore due to security. However, some users may find the accepted solution difficult to adapt due to the verbose calls to the table column names and, the need to change meta_key filter to include the table prefix.

The SQL below simplifies this a bit for users who find the SQL difficult to adapt to their own instance and makes the meta_key filter independent of the table prefix.

```
SELECT ID, user_nicename, meta_value 
FROM wp_users U JOIN wp_usermeta M ON U.ID = M.user_id 
WHERE meta_key LIKE '%capabilities' AND meta_value LIKE '%subscriber%' 
ORDER BY user_nicename;
```

The table prefix needs only to be changed for the users and usermeta in the FROM statement.

All kudos to the accepted solution, I only hope that this solution simplifies the SQL code a bit.